# Secure channel error when installing packeges in Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext, package-control

I am trying to install some packages in sublime text but when i click on a package to install it, it fails and this error appears in the console: `Secure channel error, server not providing SSL`.

Is there a way to download those pakcages manually and install them?

I deleted sublime text and installed a newer version of it but it is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the actual error message that you're seeing it's hard to say for sure what the problem you're seeing is.

However, that said, Package Control will never install a package that is not served over a secure channel (i.e. via `https` rather than `http` because of the security implications of someone maliciously injecting unauthorized code during the download.

The message you specified is listed as one of the errors of this nature; whatever tried to serve the channel/package was doing so unsecured.

That could be because you have a custom URL set up that does not serve things with a valid certificate, or it could be because the certificate chain on your system doesn't recognize the certificate being used and refuses the connection.